# Trying to parse a json

Tags: php, json

After getting a json from Youtube API. I used this code to parse it:

```
    $en = json_encode($json, true);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($en);
    echo "</pre>";
```

here is the result:

```
{"items":[{"id":"UC-D8SQfw-J-lSWFSbyX6wRg"}]}
```

I made it clear with an online json parser here's how it looks:

```
{

"items":[
    {
        "id":"UC-D8SQfw-J-lSWFSbyX6wRg"
    }
]

}
```

I want to get `id` value. I have tried `$en->items->id` but it says `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

how do I get the value of `id` ?

Comment: You have to re-decode it: `$decoded = json_decode( $en )`. Then, `$decoded->items[0]->id`

Comment: @fusion3k post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks for the help. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$en = json_encode($json, true);
$en_b = json_decode($en, true);
echo $en_b['items'][0]['id'];
```